# Creating a JUnit graph from test results

Tags: selenium, junit

Does JUnit have an OOB tool to plot the test results of a suite?  Specifically, I am using the Selenium 2 webdriver, and I want to plot passed vs failed tests.  Secondly, I want to have my tests suite continue even with a failed test, how would I go about doing this?  I tried researching the topic, but none of the answers fully addresses my question.

Thanks in advance!

Should probably put my code in here as well:

```
@Test
public void test_Suite() throws Exception {
    driver.get("www.my-target-URL.com");

    test_1();
    test_2();
}

@Test
public void test_1() throws Exception {
    //perform test
    assertTrue(myquery);
}

@Test
public void test_2() throws Exception {
    //perform test
    assertTrue(myquery);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using Jenkins as your CI server, you got [Junit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin) that will allow you to publish the results in the end of the test. And you got [Junit Graph](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+graph) to display them.